# Create Multiple Rows based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this

---

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nishu | 4 |
| 2 | Shivam | 2 |
| 3 | Himanshu | 1 |

I want to get the Output like this:-

---

| id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nishu | 4 |
| 1 | Nishu | 4 |
| 1 | Nishu | 4 |
| 1 | Nishu | 4 |
| 2 | Shivam | 2 |
| 2 | Shivam | 2 |
| 3 | Himanshu | 1 |
| 3 | Himanshu | 1 |

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cross join against `generate_series()`

```
select t.*
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(1, t.count) as g
order by t.id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/mjP_coQv)

Answer (score 1):

Using RECURSIVE CTE you can do:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte as (
  SELECT 1 as x,m.* FROM mytable m
  union all
  SELECT x+1,m.* 
  FROM cte,mytable m 
  WHERE x<m.count)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM cte
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/XNgwK7Xr)

more info:

- [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)
- [Learn PostgreSQL Recursive Query By Example](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-recursive-query/)